# Request folder locations

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to request from the user where folders are on their system so that a batch file can move files for the user from one location to another.

IE: move (Request source folder here) (Request destination folder here)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: And? Are you looking for how to get user input, or how to move files? Both of those have been answered extensively here before.

Comment: I am looking to get the user to input these locations.

Comment: I did google this, and I couldn't find anything that referenced this precisely. I may have been wording it incorrectly.

Comment: Type `set /?` for help.

Comment: Or just search StackOverflow with the right tag: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+user+input

Comment: You were to specific on your search.  As SomethingDark has already pointed out you need to sear for user input.  Not how do I ask a user where folders are on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, using a simple GUI dialog box, which will prevent typing errors or non existent directory locations being input:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "FileSpec=*.*"

Set "SourceDirectory="
Echo Please choose your source directory.
Call :GetDirectory SourceDirectory
If Not Defined SourceDirectory GoTo :EOF

Set "DestinationDirectory="
Echo Please choose your destination directory.
Call :GetDirectory DestinationDirectory
If Not Defined DestinationDirectory GoTo :EOF

Echo=Move /Y "%SourceDirectory%\%FileSpec%" "%DestinationDirectory%"
Pause

GoTo :EOF

:GetDirectory
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('^"
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile
    "(New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select your %1.',1,0).Self.Path"
^"') Do Set "%~1=%%~G"
GoTo :EOF
```

*Change the file spec for your files to be moved, (in between the `=` and `"` on line `3`).*

*If you're satisfied with the output, remove `Echo=` from line `15` to actually move the files, instead of just show the command.*

*Line `16` is include just to prevent the possible closure of the script duirng testing, you can remove it, or replace it with the rest of your commands as needed. Please do not remove line `18` and below.*